# Android: firebase checking user session not working as expected

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

**I am beginner and building register and login activities using firebase**
    I show login activity first. It has clickable text view which reads as "No account? Click here to register" when clicked it starts registration activity and allows user to register but after registering it needs to start login activity but it is not happening

**Below is Registration.java**

```
public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText etname, etmail, etpass;
private Button btnreg;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

    etname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRemail);
    etmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRemail);
    etpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRpass);
    btnreg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRreg);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
        finish();
    }
}
public void user_reg_info(View view) {

    String uname = etname.getText().toString();
    String uemail = etmail.getText().toString();
    String upass = etpass.getText().toString();
    try {
        if (uname.isEmpty() || uname.trim().equals("")) {
            etname.setError("Name cannot be empty!");
            return;
        }

        if (uemail.isEmpty() || uemail.trim().equals("")) {
            etmail.setError("Email cannot be empty!");
            return;
        }
        if (upass.isEmpty() || upass.equals("")) {
            etpass.setError("Password cannot be empty!");
            return;
        }

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering..please wait!");
        progressDialog.show();
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(uemail, upass)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Registration successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(Registration.this,Login.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Log.e("Error", task.getException().toString());
                            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

On click of register button it directly starts MainActivity

Below is Login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {


private EditText etmail,etpass;
private TextView clktoreg;
private ImageView imgLogin;
private Button btnLog;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    etmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTLemail);
    etpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTLpass);
    clktoreg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.click_2_reg);
    imgLogin = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLogin);
    btnLog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

}

public void login_user(View view) {
    String email = etmail.getText().toString();
    String pass = etpass.getText().toString();
    try {
        if (email.isEmpty() || email.trim().equals("")) {
            etmail.setError("E-mail cannot be empty!");
            return;
        }
        if (pass.isEmpty() || pass.trim().equals("")) {
            etpass.setError("Password cannot be empty!");
            return;
        } else {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in..please wait!");
            progressDialog.show();
            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(in);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                etmail.setError("Check email ID");
                                etpass.setError("Check password");

                            }

                        }
                    });


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void not_registered(View view) {

    Intent in = new Intent(this,Registration.class);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

}

Comment: Let see if i understand, you want whrn user register go to login activity and not to main activity correct?

Comment: yes! i have doubt in session checking code, not sure if it is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explain what your app does.

You register the user then the **user** is not **null** anymore, **login** activity is open and you have that in login activity:

```
if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
        finish();
}
```

Because the **user** is not **null** anymore when the login activity start and reach this condiction the mainActivity starts.

Comment: How would i correct it? MainActivity starts even if i remove this code in registration.java

Comment: Its not the registration.java its the Login.java, to fix it remove if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
        finish();
} from Login.java and see if Works.

Comment: It worked! thank you so much:) small things matters a lot!

Comment: No problem, accept answer to other people with the same problem see that you find answer.

Comment: Definitely I will!